# Check if Maven pom is SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I need a way to set a property `is.snapshot` to `0` if project is currently a *SNAPSHOT* version, otherwise set the property to `1`.

My attempt was to use the build-helper-plugin

```xml
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>version-helper</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>regex-property</goal>
                            </goals>                                
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>is.snapshot</name>
                        <value>${project.version}</value>
                        <regex>.*(-SNAPSHOT)$</regex>
                        <replacement>0</replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

If `project.version` is *SNAPSHOT* the `is.snapshot` property is set to `0`. This works fine.
However, if `project.version` is not a *SNAPSHOT* the property gets set to the `project.version`.

Any way to correct this or is there another plugin I could use?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Or for what do you need such things?

Comment: For building an rpm.

For the rpm version I want to use major.minor.service.

For rpm release I want to use 0 for SNAPSHOT or 1 for release

Comment: You know that the [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) already has such a mechanism?

Comment: I'm using the rpm-maven-plugin but the problem for me is how can I set the release to 0 when version is a SNAPSHOT and to 1 when not. The plugin sets rpm release to utc timestamp for snapshot which I don't want

Comment: In case of a SNAPSHOT why is it such a big issue ? Why not using the timestamp?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the the [release version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/rpm-mojo.html#release) of the rpm-maven-plugin manually if you really need it.